# Preload Javascript audio to play in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have a simple program where I run this script:

```
function PlayAudio(Location){
var audio = new Audio(Location);
audio.Play()
}
```

in an onclick HTML attribute.  I have a fancy loading picture that I know how to make appear and have successfully made it work.  I would like to show this picture while the audio is loading, and then make it go away after the audio file is done loading and ready to play.  Right now, there is a considerable delay between clicking the element and hearing the sound.

My trouble is knowing when the audio is done loading and ready to play.  I figure the best way to know when it's complete loading is to preload the file in-script.  I don't know how to do that.

And that's my question:
How do you preload files inside a script?
Or, is there a way to know when an audio file is finally playing?

Note:  I cannot use an `<audio>` element, unless there is some way to nest a `<div>` inside the `<audio>` so that the sound in the `<audio>` is triggered by clicking anywhere in the content of the `<div>`

Sorry for my slightly confusing descriptions!

Thanks,
Lucas N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`canplaythrough`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/canplaythrough) event

> Sent when the ready state changes to `CAN_PLAY_THROUGH`, indicating that
>   the entire media can be played without interruption, assuming the
>   download rate remains at least at the current level.

```
function PlayAudio (Location){
  var audio = new Audio;
  audio.oncanplaythrough = function(event) {
    // do stuff, e.g.; set loading `img` `style` `display` to `none`
    this.play();
  }
  audio.src = Location;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, That was exactly what I needed.  My project works flawlessly with that.

Answer (score 0):

You change its preload attr by

.   audio.preload = "auto";

It will load the whole audio file on start